# MFC: Render string in multiple formats

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Using a CDC & C`DC::DrawText(Ex)`, I want to render a string with a sub-string in bold

e.g:

```
void renderText(CDC *pDC,CString &str,int boldStart,int boldEnd)
{
...
}
```

- example: renderText(pDC,"Test
  String",0,3) -> **Test** String
- example: renderText(pDC,"Test
  String",5,-1) -> Test **String**

I assume I'll make 3 `CDC::DrawText` calls, but how do I know the positions to draw each string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CDC::GetTextExtent to get the number of pixels each piece of the string will take up, and adjust the points you pass into CDC::DrawText accordingly.